# Как убрать ВСЕ пробелы в ячейке

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Необходимо убрать все пробелы в ячейке. Использую:

```
var zavnomer = sheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
var zavnomer1 = zavnomer.replace(' ', '');
```

Но удаляет только 1 пробел, а их в значении 5 шт.

Подскажите, пожалуйста что подправить?
Спасибо.

Comment: А как убрать пробелы по всем строкам в столбце?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно

```
var zavnomer1 = zavnomer.replace(/\s/g, '');
```

Comment: Спасибо, то, что надо.